# Meteor Tracker not receiving subscriptions automatically

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze, minimongo

I'm creating some templates using Template.onCreated, and am then using Tracker.autorun to make some subscriptions and then collect data from the Server and store them on the client's MiniMongo.

Then, I can leave said Template and eventually route myself back. However, I'm noticing that upon coming back, Blaze is not capturing my changes. When routing back, it seems that onRendered is called instead of onCreated. This makes sense, however, onRendered isn't quite reacting to all my data changes yet. I've noticed it's because minimongo doesn't actually have data in it for onRendered.

However, I've noticed it can get the object by refreshing the page (thus calling onCreated and subscribing again and getting a fresh set of data from the server) My workaround is to re-subscribe in onRendered, but I feel like i shouldn't have to do this because I already initially subscribed in OnCreated. Is this an issue with Meteor, is DDP just going slow?

Let's say I have some default generic collection called Objects.

```
const Objects = new Mongo.Collection("Objects");
```

So in my onCreated I subscribe to a collection as follows

```
Template.foo.onCreated(function () {
    var self = this;

    self.autorun(function () {
        const objId= FlowRouter.getParam("id");


            self.objectSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('obj', objId, {
                onReady: function () {

                },
                onStop: function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        alert('error')
                    }
                }
            });
```

Then in onRendered I have to hack it and unnecessarily re-subscribe because I don't have objId i.e. I can't just use Objects.find(),

```
Template.foo.onRendered(function () {
    const objId= FlowRouter.getParam("id");

    Meteor.subscribe('obj', objId, {
        onReady: function () {
            $('#obj').addClass('highlight');
        },
        onStop: function (error) {
            if (error) {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
    });

    //I feel like I should just be able to do 
    //const obj = Objects.findOne({_id:objId})
    //$('#obj').addClass('highlight')

});
```

Any insights, why would I be losing data in minimongo? And is it bad practice to "re-subscribe"?

Comment: You need to show more code.. From what I can tell you want to use a helper to do what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe do the meteor tutorial before spamming stackoverflow.

Comment: More info has been added

Comment: Please show html as well. Do you have a template named "tracker"? If not then you really need to go do the meteor tutorial.

Comment: Once you have subscribed to a collection, all the changes on the collection should reflect on the client side as its reactive. Your autorun function won't be calling itself again and again as no variables inside the block is changed/updated. Hence the tracker in onCreated would be called only once. You can try subscribing the collection in the router also.

Comment: @user3807691 Mm..my misunderstanding was that the actual subscription itself is reactive and thus should trigger autorun to be called. I thought this because the subscription subscribes to a collection - and collections (or at least cursors) are reactive. I've seen workarounds with subscribing on routes, but do you think this could be inefficient or redundant. Would you recommend storing the cursor into a reactive/session var in the autorun function?

Comment: `my misunderstanding was that the actual subscription itself is reactive and thus should trigger autorun to be called` : Agreed. Thats why I am not sure why keep subscription in autorun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreated` and `onRendered` aren't reactive, but `template helpers` are. So, to constantly detect changes in those two you'd have to create a reactive context and place it inside them which can be achieved using `Tracker.autorun`. Also, be advised that it's better to keep `onRenderd` for DOM manipulations and `onCreated` for subscriptions and creation of `reactive variables`.

You don't need double subscriptions to detect changes and IMO this is generally a bad practice.

```
Template.foo.onCreated(function onCreated() {
  const self = this;
  this.autorun(function() {
  const id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
  self.subscribe('obj', id);
  });
});


Template.foo.onRendered(function onRendered() {
  const self = this;
  // this will run after subscribe completes sending records to client
  if (self.subscriptionsReady()) {
    // do whatever you want
    $('#obj').addClass('highlight');
  }
});
```